# How to check if data being added to an array already exists in a different array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-sheets

I am looking to create a simple script for a Google sheet in which array 1 will already be populated with a list of names. As a new name gets added to array 2, array 1 is checked for the name. If the name which was entered into array 2 is present in array 1 an action will be performed. This search function must take place each time a new name is added to array 2 to determine if it exists in array 1.

```
function findPlayer() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()

var picksRange = ss.getRange("B2:M15");
var poolRange = ss.getRange("B21:G96");

var picksPlayerName = picksRange.getValues(); 
var poolPlayerName = poolRange.getValues(); 

for (var i = 0; i < picksRange.length; i++)
for (var j = 0; j < poolRange.lenth; j++)

if (picksPlayerName[i] == poolPlayerName[j]) {
 poolPlayerName[i].setBackground("red")}
else {
 poolPlayerName[j].setBackground("blue");}
}
```

Comment: Post some code, this is not a difficult ask but nobody will do it from scratch.

Comment: iterate array1.  if then should work for you.

Comment: @andre-brueckner Let me know if my answer is working out for you or if you need further help.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete answer, nor does it perfectly fit your use-case, but you should be able to take it from here, or perhaps come back with another question when you have a question about a specific part of your code.

```
const existingNames = ["Carl", "Emma", "Sarah", "Ahmad"];
const newNames = ["Emma", "Sarah", "Isa", "Igor", "Kent"];

// go through the new names and check against existing ones  
newNames.forEach(newName => {
    if(existingNames.includes(newName)) {
    // handle duplicates: do nothing? 
   } else {
    // handle new names: maybe add them to the existing names?
    existingNames.push(newName);
   }
});

console.log('After going through all new names, the complete list of known names are: ' + existingNames);
```

**Demo** where you can play with the code and learn: https://jsfiddle.net/jonahe/11uom4cu/